# AJAX request in Auto-Timeout files

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have written a code, which is auto-logout when user doesn't perform any activity.
But one thing, I am not able to figure out.
I want that when I select the options from the drop-down, it will be passed to AJAX,
Can you please modify that so that I can send the data from options to AJAX.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
#idletimeout { background:#CC5100; border:3px solid #FF6500; color:#fff; font-family:arial, sans-serif; text-align:center; font-size:12px; padding:10px; position:relative; top:0px; left:0; right:0; z-index:100000; display:none; }
#idletimeout a { color:#fff; font-weight:bold }
#idletimeout span { font-weight:bold }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="idletimeout">
You will be logged off in <span><!-- countdown place holder --></span>&nbsp;seconds due to inactivity.
<a id="idletimeout-resume" href="#">Click here to continue using this web page</a> Please select reason for being idle.
<select id='idleReason' size="1">
<option value="nothing" selected="selected">Select a site</option>
<option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
<option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
<option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
<option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
</select>

</div>

Content Lorem Impsum

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.idletimer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.idletimeout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.idleTimeout('#idletimeout', '#idletimeout a', {
        idleAfter: 3,
        pollingInterval: 2,
        keepAliveURL: 'keepalive.php',
        serverResponseEquals: 'OK',
        onTimeout: function(){
                $(this).slideUp();
                window.location = "timeout.htm";
        },
        onIdle: function(){
                $(this).slideDown(); // show the warning bar
        },
        onCountdown: function( counter ){
                $(this).find("span").html( counter ); // update the counter
        },
        onResume: function(){
                $(this).slideUp(); // hide the warning bar
        }
});
//
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I would be grateful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic form of your jQuery function should look like this:

```
$('#idleReason').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.your.ajax.handler'
        data: $('#idleReason option:selected').html()
    });
);
```

You should look up the [ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more information about how to customize your query.